# Недопустимый файл Resx

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При запуске проекта вылетает ошибка:

Недопустимый файл Resx. Аргумент 'picture' должен быть рисунком, который можно использовать как Icon.

И предупреждение:

Сбой специального инструмента "ResXFileCodeGenerator".  Аргумент 'picture' должен быть рисунком, который можно использовать как Icon.

Все произведённые действия - лишь добавлял значки кнопкам и формам. Никакие файлы не трогал. Как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: Убирайте значки по одному пока не заработает.

Comment: @tym32167 Не помогло.

Comment: Из ресурсов значки тоже убрали?

Comment: @tym32167 Нет. Нужно?

Comment: Ну у вас проблема с ресурсами, я вам рекомендую удалить ресурсы. Есть вероятность, что с этим вы удалите и проблему.